# High cpu usage by process/informix

Tags: process, load, cpu, informix

I am facing a problem with my process in the production environment and I am able to simulate the issue in my dev environment as well.

The process has 5 threads of which thread 3 & 4 are highly active. `Thread 4` is a producer which queues messages and `Thread 3` is a consumer which de-queues messages. Both threads are DB intensive.

**PROBLEM**

When the process is running, the `top` output shows high cpu usage for this process & oninit(Informix). Cpu load is consistently above 4 which is dangerous.
There is only 1CPU with 2 virtual cpu's in this machine.

All the DB queries are running with `committed read` isolation level

**ANALYSIS**

1. `ps -eLo pid,ppid,lwp,nlwp,osz,rss,ruser,pcpu,stime,etime,args | grep <processname>`

This output show high cpu usage by threads 3 & 4

1. `onstat -g act -r 2`

This output shows the thread 3 & 4 queries frequently.

Considering all the above facts, is there any way to reduce the cpu usage of oninit & process and the cpu load

Answer (score 0):

On the face of it, the system is running well.  You've got two DB intensive threads which are getting served well by the data server.  Neither thread is apparently being hung up; the data server is able to keep up with the workload.  If you're not seeing waits for I/O, or significant paging activity, etc.  If you reduce the activity levels of threads 3 and 4, you should see `oninit` being less busy too.

If you're concerned by the amount of DB activity, you'll need to look at the SQL that the threads are demanding of the server.  Are the statements prepared?  Are the statistics up to date?  Can you simplify the queries?  Can you combine queries (the opposite of simplify, in many cases)?  How many queries per second are the threads requesting?

Are you sure a CPU load average of 4 is a problem?  My Mac (2.3 GHz Intel Core i7, 16 GiB RAM) is running 8 BOINC background processes and a a couple of DBMS and a web browser, etc, and has a load average varying between 4 and 10, roughly.  It is behaving perfectly well (but it isn't the same as your machine).

Comment: My machine has just 1 cpu and I read from various sources that ideal cpu load is 1 for a single cpu machine.

Comment: Is there a measurable performance problem?  Is there a measurable memory shortage (which would trigger I/O activity for paging/swapping)?  Is the only indication of trouble the CPU load average?  Is there anything else suffering on the same machine?

Comment: Yes, the machine has just 4GB memory and the machine becomes slow due to this. Also, if other processes start working, it will become additional overhead.

Comment: So, you need to decide what the workload is.  Is there a way to reduce the intensity of the DB-intensive activity in the threads?  Could you move the work into the server, perhaps using stored procedures or even UDRs, so that there is less communication needed between the client threads (producer and consumer) and the server?  What queries are those threads executing?  How many and how big/hard/bad are they?  Have you used SET EXPLAIN to monitor the number and cost of the activities?

Comment: All the queries are very simple queries based on the index. I have checked the cost of them. All have cost = 1. Is there any use in changing the isolation level to dirty read instead of committed read?

Comment: The key to reducing the workload is to reduce the number of such simple queries that are prepared (especially) and executed. Or get a machine that can keep up with the workload you're imposing on it. How many queries are you handling per message enqueued and dequeued? Do you have any extra database activity do you have going on at the same time (audit, replication)? You probably don't want to go with dirty read instead of committed read; you get grubby data that way, which usually isn't sensible.

Comment: Thread 4 is an auditing thread, which retrieves the messages from db say every 1 sec and queue it. There may be 4 selects and 2 updates for enqueue and similar for dequeue.

Comment: And how many messages are there to process every second?  Where are they coming from?  How are they being inserted?  Are they ever deleted?  (You only mention updates — unless updates means any update operation, not just UPDATE statements — so something must be inserting the messages, and maybe something is deleting them eventually.)  What are the size of the data rows being manipulated?  How are the rows to be enqueued and dequeued found?  Is it a complex search?  Is it properly indexed?  Aaargh...so many questions, with no knowing which, if any, might be the crucial ones?

Comment: The thread will query DB (`select * from messages where attentiontime < currenttime`). There may be many messages ranging from 1 to 1000. There is also an expiry time after which messages will be deleted from db. After dequeueing/processing , the attention time will be updated so that it is again processed after some time. The same message is to be periodically processed. This applies to all the messages in the table. It can range from 1 to millions of messages.

Comment: Which version of Informix are you running? What does your onconfig.instance_name file look like? Perhaps tweaking the tunable parameters could improve performance?